# How can I prove/disprove that f is a contraction mapping?

Tags: analysis, functions, contraction-mapping

How can I prove that this function: $ f: X \rightarrow X \text{ with } X = [1, \infty)$ (The metric is the absolute value)

$f(x) = x+\frac{1}{x}$ is not a contraction mapping?
I think it isn't because I'd have to find an $L<1$ such that $d(f(x), f(y)) \leq L \cdot d(x, y)$ for all $x,y \in X.$
I don't think that's possible because for every L that I can find, there are always still $x,y \in X$ for which the inequality won't hold.

However, I was also not able to pick $x,y$ to prove the negation.

I have come so far: $$d(f(x), f(y)) = |x-y + \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}| = |(x-y)(1-\frac{1}{xy})| = (1-\frac{1}{xy})\cdot d(x,y)$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know Banach's fixed point theorem?

Comment: Can  you see that $(1-\frac{1}{xy}) \le L < 1$ is not satisfied for large $x, y$?

Comment: @red_trumpet I do know it, however as far as I know it can only be used if I have a contraction mapping already (?)

Comment: Try a proof by contradiction!

Comment: @MartinR That's what I was wondering about. I know it converges to 1, but I can't actually find x,y so that it's not less than 1. That's why I am stuck

Comment: $(1-\frac{1}{xy}) \le L < 1$ must be satisfied for some fixed $L$ and *all* $x, y \ge 1$. That is not possible.

Comment: @red_trumpet I will try that! Thank you!

Comment: @MartinR I know, but I don't think that reasoning would satisfy my tutors  :-)

Comment: @red_trumpet it worked very well! thank you for helping!

Comment: I personally like red_trumpet's contradiction idea better but it's also worth noting that since $f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^2}\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$, you can observe that $f$ is not a contraction mapping, since if it were we must have $|f'(x)|\leq L$ at each $x$.